# Disabling all the combinations for a modifier with AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

With the `AutoHotKey` script

```
LWin::
return
```

the `Left Windows` key can be completely disabled. Not only is a simple `Left Windows` hit disabled, but also any other combinations including a `Left Windows` key, has no effect, as the `Left Windows` key were not pressed.
For example: `LWin+E`, which normally opens an Explorer window, will just send an "`e`".

Never the less, as soon as a new mapping using the Left Windows key is defined, all the rest of the `Left Windows` keybindings return active. For example, with the script:

```
LWin::
return


LWin & a::
Send foo
return
```

`LWin + a` will print "`foo`". `Left Windows` alone will do nothing. But, magically, `Left Windows + E` will open an Explorer Window.

How could I disable a modifier (like `LWin`, `RWin`, `LAlt`, `RAlt`, `LCtrl`, `RCtrl`) so that none of the keybinding (but the ones I explicitily defined) run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify every `LWin` combination you wish to disable.

```
LWin::
LWin & e::    ; this combinations is disabled
return


LWin & a::
tooltip, foo
return
```

Every other default combination will still work, unless you disable it.

You can do it in a different way, if you are unwilling to write every combination.
It it a little less reliable since you are using `Send` now.

```
global LWin_g := 0 

SetTimer , checkLWin , 25
return


checkLWin:
    if( GetKeyState( "LWin" , "P") )
        LWin_g := 1
    else
        LWin_g := 0
return

$e::
    if( LWin_g )
    {
        tooltip, action 
    }
    else
    {
        Send ,e
    }
return

LWin::  
return
```

Comment: This is what I feared. Sad to know that.

Comment: great! Your solution is amazing!